# Why does EJS not accept absolute paths for includes?

Tags: node.js, express, layout, ejs, template-engine

According to the EJS github page, EJS should accept absolute paths for `include` files but it doesn't work for me.

So this does not work

```
<% include views/partials/global/header.ejs %>
```

I just get the error stating *Could not find the include file "views/partials/global/header.ejs"*

But this does work:

```
<% include ../../partials/global/header.ejs %>
```

How do you enable it to work? This is the Git commit that says absolute paths should work https://github.com/tj/ejs/pull/157/commits

Comment: What problem you have excatly? What's your code? What error do you get? or if you don't get any error, what's the output you expect and you don't get? You are not new to already have read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Soooo, how is my answer going? We waste free time here for you. At least give a bit of feedback... :-(

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I ended up switching to Handlebars.js after struggling with these view engines. EJS just doesn't do what I thought it could. But your answer was very helpful in that the change was not actually part of the main EJS repository. I know little about GIT so couldn't understand more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I noticed the problem.

That commit is not merged in the main branch, hence is not inside the version you have downloaded. That's a "Pull request". That's the code that someone has written but is not pulled inside the main source code of the repository.

The actual repository with that code is the one where the "Pull request" comes from, which is this one:
[image]
so if you want that piece of code, you should head to that repository (by clicking just there), download it and **manually** place it where it should be. Note that you will download the version standing there, which is kinda old.

You can algo get the diff and also **manually** edit the files you have now installed, so you keep the latest changes while merging this commits. Not an easy job as a lot of things can be broken after 5 years of releases (maybe not as `ejs` is an abandoned project).

Another way is to use `git` tools. Download the main repository and then merge the pull request, which is the same as doing it amnually and has exactly the same problems, with the addition that collisions can happen and is a more tedious work if you are a newbie with git.

I guess you need to read a small tutorial on how a git repository (and GitHub) works, as this is just a small part and you are going to face more problems if you just look for commits thinking that they are merged. There are releases, branches and a lot of stuff to follow when you compare a GitHub version with the thing you installed from the npm.